# Bitnami Concrete5-5.7.5.2-0 instance is not loading themes properly

Tags: bitnami, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

When adding concrete5 theme into `application/themes/my_custom_theme` bitnami instance does not recognize new theme. It recognizes it when moving theme into `concrete/themes/my_custom_theme`. Issue is only that in the current concrete5 version (5.7.5.2-0 ) custom themes should be stored in application/themes. My local concrete5 (same version 5.7.5.2-0) works when I keep the themes in application/themes folder. How come Bitnami version does not follow the concrete5 updated version structure? I do not want to move my theme folder around between local environment and production because of this. Is there some way to fix this properly?

Comment: What if you add it to a package? That way you can also bundle all of your other custom stuff in there too :)

Comment: Thanks Nicolai, I will try it out... it is shame that I need to go down that road. Maybe it is better in the long run, but now it feels a bit as an overkill :)

Comment: Yeah, it might seem a bit overkill for just a theme. But before you know it, you will have to add a bunch of other stuff - and then you'll thank me ;) Let us know if it worked

Comment: Agree with @NicolaiDitlevKroghKrüger. The work of creating a controller file, an icon and some other files is  definetely worth it! - Don't forget to check permissions on the package folder

Comment: @Daenu the only needed file is the controller - correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @NicolaiDitlevKroghKrüger. It depends if you want to put your theme on the marketplace, then the icon is a must. But basically you're right